# Running command on remote windows server and add results to a text file

Tags: batch, psexec, sysinternals

I am trying to find the installed version of a piece of software on a lot of servers (800+).

The command is: "dsmqver -f 2" which returns output like "Version:     7.5.0.2"

I have been trying to automate the process with PsExec from sysinternals, but I don't quite get the output I want.

Currently my command looks like this:

```
PsExec.exe @servers.txt -u myDomain\myUsername -p myPassword dspmqver -f 2 >>results.txt
```

It runs through the listed servers in the servers.txt file and runs the command - that part works, but the output is sorted in a useless way.

An example of the outpput is:

```
Version:     7.5.0.2
Version:     7.5.0.4
\\server1:
\\server2:
\\server3:
```

The problem is, that server2 don't have MQ installed and it is offline. From the output I can't tell which servers has the software installed and which doesn't or if the server is online at all.

Is there a smarter what do stuff like this?

Best regards

Rasmus

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap this in a batch command.

Pseudo code:

```
For server in serverlist{
 status = PsExec.exe - args
 echo %server% status is %status%
}
```

Then run thisFile.bat >> logfile.txt and you should get a nice little list like

```
Server 1 is Version:     7.5.0.2
Server 2 is Version:     7.5.0.2
Server 3 is 
Server 4 is Version:     7.5.0.2  and so on
```